# How to initialize Variable based on DataType in Android Studio Live Template?

Tags: android, android-studio, live-templates

I am trying to create a live template in which based on the datatype i need to initialize the variable.

Eg): `String result = "";` `boolean result = true; int result = 0;`

How can i edit this in live template? 
My Code snippet:

```
public $EXTRA_CLASS3$ getResult() {
    $EXTRA_CLASS3$ $EXTRA_VAR$; // Need the initialization here based on datatype
    //Some Operation using $EXTRA_VAR$
    return $EXTRA_VAR$;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: $EXTRA_CLASS3$ will be defined from outside;

Comment: So if i change the datatype there it should be initialized automatically..